# Finding the infimum and supremum of an interval

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, supremum-and-infimum

If I have $T = (1,2]$

I want to find infimum and supremum:

$\inf(T)$ is not possible / or negative infinity

$\sup(T) = 2$

Is this correct?

It is the $\inf(T)$ that I am confused about

Thank you.

Comment: Check the definition of infimum and see if it fits to your answer.

Comment: What would you guess?

Comment: @copper.hat he already gave his guess in the question

Comment: Very loosely, think of $\inf,\sup$ as $\min, \max$. What would your guess be then?

Comment: @copper.hat I think you should empathize on the word $loosely$ there.

Comment: @theSongbird: I will try to empathize with the word loosely.

Comment: Thank you for your responses *she.    In doing these types that I have came across, e.g. S=[1,2] I have from this that sup(S)=2, and inf(T)=1 from what you have said respectively. However the notion of the change in bracket as ( rather than [ has me somewhat perplexed. Does the change in bracket not actually mean anything? I would think logically that it would be inf(T) ≥ 1, but I am assuming that this is wrong :/

Comment: @princetongirl818 sorry about that! The change in bracket does *not* affect the sup/inf, but of course it means *something*. Do you understand the difference between the sets being described?

Comment: dw haha. From my understanding it means that the lowest value of (1,3] for example is not 1. But [1,3] can take the lowest value of 1.

Comment: Right, so $(1,3] = \{x : 1 < x \leq 3\}$.  Certainly, then, $(1,3]$ has a lower bound.  It *doesn't* however, have a minimum (lowest element).

Answer (score 2):

$\inf(T)$ means the greatest lower-bound of $T$.  We may state, for example, that all elements of $T$ are positive, so $0$ is a lower bound of $T$, which means that $\inf(T) \geq 0$.  So your conclusion is clearly wrong.

In fact, we have $\inf(T) = 1$.  Note that it is not necessary for $\inf(T)$ to be an element of $T$.